# Nest thermost not working with Rheem A/C C wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, nest

My A/C unit was recently replaced. I have a Rheem RGEA14036AJT06XAB. The techs installed a pretty bare-bones thermostat since my old thermostat was reading 5 degrees off. So I decided it was a good time to upgrade to the Nest Thermostat E. Based on the wiring to my old thermostat, it seemed like everything would be good. I had the Rc Y G W and C wires hooked up before the A/C was replaced. And the old thermostat was working when the replaced the unit, it was just reading the temperature wrong. Based on that, I hooked the 5 wires up. But when I went to test it on the Nest, the Fan will work, but the 'Cooling' test fails. The blower starts for a moment and then immediately stops. However, if I disconnect the C wire, the A/C pump runs just fine and I get cold air.

A tech support guy at Nest/Google advised me to run it with just the 4 wires without the C for now and to contact a Nest Pro, but I wanted to get a better idea of what's going wrong first.

I have tested the C wire with a multimeter and it is reading 24V, so it seems that it should be working, but it's not.

Comment: When you say "you tested the C wire with a multimeter" which two wires did you have your multimeter probes connected to?

Comment: The red Rc wire and the blue C wire